# key bindings visual studio 2013 to switch tabs

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I was wondering if there are any hotkeys by default key bindings I can add to Visual Studio 2013 to switch tabs.  I know you can ctrl+tab and shift+ctrl+tab to go forward and backwards in VS13's list of open tabs, but I prefer i Xcode or sublime text where you can just cmd+shift+] or cmd+shift+[ to go to the right tab or left tab respectively.  Does anyone know if there is a way for this?  I can't seem to find one.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it.  I don't know why I couldn't find this before:

http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Configuring_Keyboard_Shortcuts.html

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcuts in VS can be configured in Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard.  You can find commands either by searching for their name ("Show commands containing:") or by pressing a known shortcut and seeing which commands it's mapped to ("Press shortcut keys:").

It looks like you need to set `Window.NextDocumentNav` and `Window.PreviousDocumentNav`.